# How do R packages like RJags and RStan handle interprocess communication?

Tags: r, ipc, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

How do R packages that communicate with external programs like stan and jags handle the interprocess communication? I can imagine it's feasible with a system() call and/or input/output to files, but I'm guessing they do it in a more elegant way.

Comment: don't know about RStan, but I'm pretty sure that the JAGS and BUGS interfaces just use file I/O and system calls.  You could look at the source code ...